# MySQL query result store in dictionary with one column as key

Tags: python, mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I stumbled across this issue when trying to generate a dynamic inventory file in ansible.  The host information was stored in MySQL table. Which looks like this.

```
Ip status
1.1.1.1 23
2.2.2.2 21
3.3.3.3 23
4.4.4.4 23
5.5.5.5 21
```

I could query this in python but how do I create a dictionary that takes status as key and create dictionary with exact one key as the status coulm with all values assigned to one key.

Eg.

```
Dict[21] - {2.2.2.2, 5.5.5.5}
Dict2[23] - {1.1.1.1, 3.3.3.3, 4.4.4.4}
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can use aggregation for this. If you want the list of `ip`s as a CSV string:

```
select status, group_concat(ip) as ips
from mytable
group by status
```

You might prefer a JSON array:

```
select status, json_arrayagg(ip) as ips
from mytable
group by status
```

Comment: Thanks. Can we do this directly in python as eventually multiple status will be clubbed based on deployment requirment in ansible.

Comment: @DilerSingh: your data is stored in a database table, so it will be more efficient to do the aggregation in the database, using above queries, then retrieve the result from python.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your input in a file name "ip.txt", you can do:

```
a = {}

with open("ip.txt") as file:
    for l in file:
       b=l.rstrip('\n').split(' ')
       if b[1] in a:
          a[b[1]] = a[b[1]] + ',' + b[0]
       else:
          a[b[1]] = b[0]

print(a)
```

output:
`{'status': 'Ip', '23': '1.1.1.1,3.3.3.3,4.4.4.4', '21': '2.2.2.2,5.5.5.5'}`

NOTE: I am not a python developer, so there might be room for improvement in this code.